# How to pass parameter to getFooAttribute() megic method from view on Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I'm newbie in Laravel. I would like to pass parameter from view side to getFooAttribute method. Below is my needed method.

```
class Patient extends Model
{
    public function getFooAttribute($paramfromview){
        return SomeModel::find($paramfromview);
    } 
}
```

This is code from view side.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="some" value="{{$somepatient->foo($someparameter)}}" class="form-control" >
</div>
```

I'm not sure is it possible to do that. Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: the get method is called by model, however you can just display the model, why are you  using the model to call another model?

Comment: that's not how accessor work sir https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators